# Get part of a page url

Tags: posts, pages, content

I've been searching for this, but I can't find the answer.
 What I want to do:
 Every post will have a link to a page and that page needs to get the content of the post (the current post from where the link has been clicked)
 So first I have to pass the post ID of the current post to the url of the page we will click on, and when we get to that page I need to get the ID from the current page url into the page's content so I can get the post content by ID
 example:
 I am viewing a post (that has the post id 12), www.example.com/current-post and somewhere in the post I have a dynamic link  www.example.com/modify-post-here?post_id=`enter code here` would lead to www.example.com/modify-post-here?post-id=12 (currently the page will not pass the ID, it is removing this part of the url post-id=12, and only shows the question mark)
and this page needs to take the content (just plain text) of the post I was viewing when I clicked the link (the post with id 12, in this case) , and make it editable so it can be sent in a form.

Your help is much appreciated
Thank you

Comment: The link works fine in my test: `<a href="http://example.com/modify-post-here?post-id=12">Edit</a>`. You can try to deactivate all plugins and / or switch the theme to rule out a conflict.

Comment: ok, thanks, but I am more interested in how to get the content of the post as described

Comment: You said something was stripping out the `post-id=12` part of the url. WordPress should not be doing that. I suggested disabling plugins to get it working.

Comment: Yes but that is not the problem. My question is another one.. but I doubt someone will reply now

Comment: Sorry, what _is_ your question?